# How to properly use the .NET cryptography services

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

I am needing to implement a symmetric algorithm for a network protocol. I already coded the `ICryptoTransform` class and it works.

Now I am a bit confused of the responsibilities of the `SymmetricAlgorithm` class (inherited by `AesManaged`, DES and all others algorithms). Every example I found on internet only uses it once and no one explains what the full responsibilities of this class are.

For example, if I use it for network communication:

Should I create a `SymmetricAlgorithm` instance for every connection to the socket and let it hold the key? Or should I save the key outside my implementation of `SymmetricAlgorithm` and use the instance just as static class or create a new instance every time I wanna encrypt/decrypt something for a already used connection?

---

Because my algorithm doesn't use a initialization vector but there is no random salt. That salt would be equal to the number of bytes encrypted using the actual key, so I am confused if my implementation of `SymmetricAlgorithm` must hold this "salt" or I must save that salt outside of the instance and pass it as parameter every time I call `CreateEncryptor` or `CreateDecryptor`.

Should my implementation of `SymmetricAlgorithm` hold all the information about the encryption?

Comment: Your block cipher doesn't use an IV?  Hmmmm... Sounds like you should fix that first.

Comment: @LukePark It uses a IV in special cases but the IV is just the number of bytes already ciphered.
I know is not strong but I am not implementing this for my own, I am reverse engineering a protocol and its the way the encryption works..